# Change Color of Negative Button when It is clicked

Tags: java, android

```
.setNegativeButton("Favorite", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        fav=true;
                        user = db.userDao().findByName(email);
                        if(user.getmFavorite()==null)
                        {
//                            Log.i("Check List", user.getmFavorite());
                            Log.i("Number1", "Numer1");
                            //String favorite = user.getmFavorite();
                            user.setmFavorite(newFav);
                            Context context = getActivity();
                            fav = true;
                            toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Favorited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                            Log.i("Check List", user.getmFavorite());

                            db.userDao().Update(user);
                        }
                        else{

                            String favorites = user.getmFavorite();
                            tokenize(favorites);
                            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(items);
                            if(set.contains(newFav))
                            {
                                Log.i("Number221", "Numer221");
                                Log.i("Check List", user.getmFavorite());
                                Context context = getActivity();
                                fav = true;
                                toast = Toast.makeText(context, "This user is already favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Log.i("Number331", "Numer331");
                                Log.i("Check List", user.getmFavorite());
                                String fav2 = favorites + "," + newFav;
                                user.setmFavorite(fav2);
                                Context context = getActivity();
                                fav = true;
                                toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Favorited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.show();
                                Log.i("Check List2", user.getmFavorite());
                                db.userDao().Update(user);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                })
```

Hello I want to change the color of Button when I click the Negative button. 
So if Negative Button was red , and I click it it should change to Blue, and If I click Positive Button change Negative Button's color to red. I dont know how to do this ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this -

```
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            if(clicked)
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.YOUR_COLOR_NAME));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it straight, you simply want to change the button's colour from red to blue and vice-versa each time someone presses the button. You were kind of ambiguous in the objective.

The easiest way I know of doing that is using a flag to see which colour is supposed to be on the button. You also have the setBackgroundColor method that programmatically changes the color.

So I would do something like

```
if(!isRed)
btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
else
btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

being that red and blue are custom colours. You can make them in your colors.xml file.

You need to have the setBackground method inside onClick to make sure it's triggered.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
View alertDialog= View.inflate(this.getActivity(), R.layout.alert_dialog,
                                        null);

builder.setTitle(getLocalizedString("Message"))
        .setView(eventEditDialogView)
        .setPositiveButton(getLocalizedString("Ok"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(getLocalizedString("Cancel"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        })
return builder.create();
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
 Button positive = ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
 positive.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
 positive.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GrayBGColor));
 }
```

it helps you